# ERROR: make sure the Makefile and checksum file (/usr/pkgsrc/x11/gtk3/distinfo) are up to date

Tags: gnome, make, bsd, checksum, netbsd

To install Gnome on NetBSD, I did so:

```
#cd /usr/pkgsrc/meta-pkgs/gnome
#make fetch-list|sh
```

And waited until all dependencies downloaded, then typed:

```
#make install clean
```

Build started, and after a while I ran into the following error:

> ERROR: make sure the Makefile and checksum file (/usr/pkgsrc/x11/gtk3/distinfo) are up to date, if you want override this check, type "/usr/bin/make NO_CHECKSUM=yes [other args]"

Does anybody know why this error is happening, and what is the best solution.

The error is shown in the following image:
[image]

Comment: what version of NetBSD and pkgsrc are you using?

Comment: @schaiba NetBSD version 7.0 and I got pkgsrc from host: **ftp.NetBSD.org** package directory: **pub/pkgsrc/stable**

Comment: You might want to report this to the appropriate NetBSD mailing list. If you're in a hurry, you can use `NO_CHECKSUM=yes` as suggested.

Comment: @schaiba Thanks. **gtk+-3.16.7.tar.xz** was not fetched properly. Fetched it again, problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the *checksum* error. Size of `/usr/pkgsrc/distfiles/gtk+-3.16.7.tar.xz` is around **677KB** but on remote ftp site is around **18MB**. Therefore, the file is not downloaded properly. Deleted local file with `rm /usr/pkgsrc/distfiles/gtk+-3.16.7.tar.xz` and ran `make fetch-list|sh` again, and then `make install clean`. Problem solved. But I don't know why I didn't receive any error message in the first place when `gtk+-3.16.7.tar.xz` couldn't be fetched properly.